# Powershell Output saved to text file and write to console

Tags: powershell, text, scripting, ip

i am new to powershell, i am trying to make a simple test-connection script that will ping a camera and say if its up or down and if its down save to a txt file.
My issue is, the output in the console works properly but when i go to view the text file it has other random camera names.

```
[string[]]$CamIP = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\johni\Documents\Cams\CamsIP.txt'
[string[]]$CamName = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\johni\Documents\Cams\CamNames.txt'
function Get-TimeStamp { return "[{0:MM/dd/yy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date) }
while ($True) {
for ($i = 0; $i -lt ($CamIP.Length); $i++) {
if (Test-Connection $CamIP[$i] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { write-host -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black  $CamName[$i] "Cam is Up" (Get-Date) }
 else {write-host -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black $CamName[$i] "Cam is Down" (Get-Date)}
if (Test-Connection $CamIP[$i] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {write-output $CamName[$i] "Cam is Down" (Get-Date) >> 'C:\Users\johni\Documents\Cams\Down Times.txt'}}
Start-Sleep -seconds 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue,
i forgot to add -NOT on the line that writes to the text file